# Unable to initialize environment variables on startup

Tags: bash, cron, python, raspberry-pi

I have written a python script that runs successfully on raspberry pi if it is run manually from the console. As I want to start the script on reboot, I've written a bash script to change directory, set up the  environment and run the python script. Upon checking the log, however, I have noticed that an error occurs when trying to import a library. Upon executing the following line:

```
from openvino.inference_engine import IENetwork, IEPlugin
```

an error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "realtime_objectdetection_and_tracking_async.py", line 23, in <module>
    from custom_module... ImportError: No module named 'openvino.inference_engine'
```

If I run the same line from the console, there is no error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/workspace/counting-cars-with-backend-conn $ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39)  [GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on
linux Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from openvino.inference_engine import IENetwork, IEPlugin
```

Therefore, as OpenVINO installation added to .bashrc the following line:

```
# OpenVINO
source ~/inference_engine_vpu_arm/bin/setupvars.sh
```

I tried to do the same in the startup script before running the python script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/pi/inference_engine_vpu_arm/bin/setupvars.sh 
cd /home/pi/workspace/counting-cars-with-backend-conn 
python3 realtime_objectdetection_and_tracking_async.py &
```

Then I added the script to cron table by running crontab -e:

```
@reboot sh /home/pi/run_object_detection_and_tracking.sh
```

As this doesn't fix the issue (ImportError above), I don't know what should be additionally configured/modified in order to get the same behaviour as in the case of running the python script from the console.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Does your `sh` shell have a `source` command? Does it work if you use `. /home/pi/inference_engine_vpu_arm/bin/setupvars.sh` instead of `source ...`?

Comment: I believe the reason for this is dew to the fact that when booting up vs being booted and at the console, the things/resources available are not the same. Like while booting: X is not available, so things that require X are not nor should not be ran yet. vino is a desktop sharing app and requires X.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting your script in /etc/init.d and putting a symlink to it in /etc/rc5.d and make sure the script is chmod +x. This should run your script at a time that has the same things available as at the terminal when already booted. Thus it should no longer throw errors.

Reference: [Run Levels on Linux](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3222070/linux/maneuvering-around-run-levels-on-linux.html)